# Node.js: Error: Cannot find module 'stack'

Tags: macos, node.js

I tried to install [howtonode.org](https://github.com/creationix/howtonode.org)  on my Osx

```
cd ~/Sites/
git clone git@github.com:creationix/howtonode.org
```

My context is the following:

```
OSx version: 10.7.4
node -v v0.6.15
```

When I try to run the following command

```
~/Sites/howtonode.org node server/server.js &
```

I get the following error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'stack'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antoniopierro/Sites/howtonode.org/server/server.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)

[1]+  Exit 1                  node server/server.js
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `node ~/Sites/howtonode.org/server/server.js &` or go to `~/Sites/howtonode.org/server/` and run`node server`

Also, you have not installed the dependencies from package.json.

Go to `~/Sites/howtonode.org/` and type inn `npm install`. This will install all the dependencies in `~/Sites/howtonode.org/node_modules`. You can then run the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I get the same error :-(

Comment: ok this time it works...just another question, these additional module, like `stack` and `creationix`, are installed globally or locally for the `howtonode.org ` application?

Comment: Node and npm uses local installations. You can install packages globally( if you want to use them as tools from the command line) using the -g option. Ex: `npm install -g jslint`. If you are on a mac you have to use sudo like this: `sudo npm install -g jslint`